# Wish to format cell text colors in a PDF so they can not change

Tags: document-library

For some reason when uploading a PDF file, it changes the font color of the title of said PDF file and I can't change the text color to match the rest of the text.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the document after you've uploaded it to see if it is actually changed or if it's just the browser's default renderer handling it differently?

Comment: It's not the color of the text in the document. But, the color of the title in the cells after I upload the pdf.

Comment: So is this a document that is being populated by SharePoint and output as a word file or is this just a static PDF file created elsewhere that is changing on upload?

Comment: Its a static PDF file from elsewhere. I have since figured out a way to achieve what I wanted. But, I wanted a more elegant and long term solution. Not to mention quicker method of dealing with the issue.

Comment: Do you have any images to show of what is happening?

Comment: file:///U:/2017-08-22%2011_40_38-Compliance%20-%20Operations%20Policies%20-%20Internet%20Explorer.png  The PDF title font color keeps changing when I add the PDF file link. And I can't just go Format Text tab on the ribbon and change it to the color I prefer.

Comment: That appears to be an image on a local drive.

Comment: Cards on the table: I am in charge of making the company policy website function and look good. I have/had 0 experience with share point before this job. long story short: the policies are linked to a shared local drive. When I upload said documents it changes the font color of the titles. And I can not change the color back without unlinking the document and starting over from scratch. While editing them in Share Point